# Correct way to insert an if/else statement inside const in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, variables, if-statement, syntax

I keep getting a synax error and I'm not sure how to do this any other way:

```
    const new_datas = [
      if(this.state.username != '') {
      {
        name: "Plaza",
        route: "TabNav",
        icon: require("../img/plaza_party.png"),
        bg: "#C5F442"
      },
      {
        name: `${this.state.thefirstname}'s Profile`,
        route: "ProfileScreen",
        icon: require("../img/pass.png"),
        bg: "#C5F442"
      },
    }
    else{
      {
        name: "Plaza",
        route: "TabNav",
        icon: require("../img/plaza_party.png"),
        bg: "#C5F442"
      },
      {
        name: "Login/Sign Up",
        route: "LoginScreen",
        icon: require("../img/pass.png"),
        bg: "#477EEA",
      },
    }
  ];
```

Basically what should happen is once the username is stored in state it should update the contents then switch from `Login/Signup` to `this.state.firstname Profile`. Is there any correct way to achieve this ?

Edit: Extra code:

```
<List
        dataArray={new_datas}
        renderRow={data =>
          <ListItem
            button
            noBorder
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data.route)}
          >
            <Left>
              <Image
                active
                source={data.icon}
                style={{ height: 50, width: 50 }}
              />
              <Text style={styles.text}>
                {data.name}
              </Text>
            </Left>

            {data.types &&
              <Right style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Badge
                  style={{
                    borderRadius: 3,
                    height: 25,
                    width: 72,
                    backgroundColor: data.bg
                  }}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={styles.badgeText}
                  >{`${data.types} Types`}</Text>
                </Badge>
              </Right>}
          </ListItem>}
      />
```

This part will not change once I have logged in.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) is what you're after:

```
const new_datas = props.username ? [
  {
    name: "Plaza",
    route: "TabNav",
    icon: require("../img/plaza_party.png"),
    bg: "#C5F442"
  },
  {
    name: `${this.state.thefirstname}'s Profile`,
    route: "ProfileScreen",
    icon: require("../img/pass.png"),
    bg: "#C5F442"
  } 
]:[
  {
    name: "Plaza",
    route: "TabNav",
    icon: require("../img/plaza_party.png"),
    bg: "#C5F442"
  },
  {
    name: "Login/Sign Up",
    route: "LoginScreen",
    icon: require("../img/pass.png"),
    bg: "#477EEA",
  },
];
```

Comment: Thank you, but this still isn't working. But something odd did happen, when I add `!` (false) to `props.username`  and hot reloaded then it worked. Not sure what's going on there. I added more of my code above.

Answer (score 1):

use let, if there's not username assign some value

```
let new_datas = [];

  if(this.state.username != '') {

    new_datas = [{
      name: "Plaza",
      route: "TabNav",
      icon: require("../img/plaza_party.png"),
      bg: "#C5F442"
    },
    {
      name: `${this.state.thefirstname}'s Profile`,
      route: "ProfileScreen",
      icon: require("../img/pass.png"),
     bg: "#C5F442"
    },]
  }else{

    new_datas = [{
      name: "Plaza",
      route: "TabNav",
      icon: require("../img/plaza_party.png"),
      bg: "#C5F442"
    },
    {
      name: "Login/Sign Up",
      route: "LoginScreen",
      icon: require("../img/pass.png"),
      bg: "#477EEA",
    },]
  }
```

Comment: yeah, the same thing is happening like Jonathan Rys's answer. I'm sure it works but `{data.name}` just isn't updating unless I refresh the app. Not sure if this will help, but the `if else` code is inside of `render()` and the rest of the code is inside of `return();`

Comment: which library are  you using?

Comment: I'm using the react-native native base kitchen sink: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink I'm only using the drawer part of the code

Comment: For something a lot more similar to mine: https://github.com/GeekyAnts/native-base-react-navigation-stack-navigator/blob/master/src/SideBar/SideBar.js

Comment: yeah it works on there. My last attempt is to try to make the `return()` dynamic. So there will be a whole `if statement` with the same code but different dataArray. And for `new_datas` I'll put in the after log in code and a new variable: `old_datas` which is before the log in code.

Comment: Ok I found the problem, everything is working technically, but this.state.username keeps defining as `null` in the drawer until I reopen the app. Even though I pulled the stored username from AsyncStorage

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have two objects declaration inside if and else braces. Are you missing array braces and variable names?

If I were to do it I first need to find the triggering event to username like input field onChange event then let that event trigger a function. Inside the triggered function I will add a setState username. Then inside the render function I will add the condition that evaluates the this.state.username.

Comment: Ok instead of the if statement inside the const, I put the const inside the if statement like this: `if (this.state.username) {
      const truedata =  new_datas;
    } else {
      const truedata = datas;
    }``    But for some reason I getting an error saying it can't find the variable.